How can I point a void pointer to different objects that share have different implementations of a virtual function?
I have a pointer that I'd like to point to different instances of classes that share an abstract base class, and then call a function on the pointer that each child class has its own implementation of (defined as virtual in the base class). Is this possible at all?
I initially tried this which I now understand why it doesn't work (I think):
class Base{
    virtual int Foo() = 0;
}

class Child1: public Base{
    int Foo() override;
}

class Child2: public Base{
    int Foo() override;
}

Child1 child1;
Child2 child2;

void *ptr;

switch (expression)
{
case 1:
    ptr = &child1;
    break;
case 2:
    ptr = &child2;
    break;

default:
    break;
}

ptr->Foo();


ptr should not be a void* -- it should be a Base*. As a rule of thumb, if you use void* in C++, you're probably doing something wrong.

Read the introduction to polymorphism in a good book.

@ChristianStieber thank you, but in this case, Base is an abstract class due to Foo() being purely virtual (I'll add that detail in), so I can't create instances of it. Any alternatives you can think of?

Base * is not an "instance of Base", so it works regardless of it beng abstract.

Base* base = &child1; is valid. Base KO = child; (copy with slicing) would be invalid.

In addition to what @ChristianStieber said, try to refrain from using raw pointers in general and try to use smart pointers instead.

@AndréLehto ptr is non-owning here. a smart pointer would be incorrect

@Caleth You are right.

It does not work because void type has no method Foo because it is not a class. This is not python, symbols must be resolvable at compile-time.

To answer your question, static_cast<Base*>(ptr)->Foo(); (but you'd also need to fix your case statement to do ptr = static_cast<Base*>(&child1)).  However, follow the advice that others have already mentioned about avoiding void* in the first place.

When you use virtual functions, create your objects using std::make_unique. E.g. std::unique_ptr<Base> child1_ptr = std::make_unique<Child1>() Now you have modeled both ownership and you will use polymorphic classes correctly. (In general you will never see the derived classes again)

C++, in general, is a statically typed language: at every point in the source code, the compiler knows the "type" of objects. Yes, I'm simplifying things a bit here.
Your void* ptr merely tells the compiler that ptr points to "something" -- but the compiler has no clue what that "something" might be, and this isn't stuff like Javascript or python where it would just look at the "something" to determine what it is. You try to use that void* ptr for pretty much anything, and the compiler will just tell you "sorry, I can't do that" simply because it has absolutely no clue what it is looking at.
If, instead, you change your code to Base* ptr, then the compiler knows that this ptr will point to something that's at least a Base. It doesn't know what the derived class is, but that's what the virtual is for -- the compiler can call a virtual function on a Base object, and it will end up in whatever derived class we are really looking at.
Also, as a side-effect, the compiler won't let you assign anything to your ptr that's not a pointer to a Base-object. For example, static char evil[]="evil"; ptr=evil; would have worked in your version of the code, but not in the fixed one: evil is definitely "something", so you can certainly let void* ptr point to it. However, evil is clearly not a Base, so the compiler refuses to let you assign it to ptr in the fixed version.
That's also why you'll rarely find void* stuff in C++ code -- there really isn't much you can do with it, other than casting it into what you think it should be. But that's error-prone, and thus something you want to avoid doing.

Thank you so much! I wasn't aware that you could create pointers to an abstract class.

If you think about it, it's not pointing to an (instance of an) "abstract class" -- it's still pointing to a Child1 or Child2 class. It's just that these objects are ALSO instances of the Base class, which is what we're generally interested in when using virtual functions.

I see. Thanks again, I obviously wasn't grasping the concept correctly.
